# Is there an easy way to convert to PDO

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pdo

On my website I use both a postgresql and mysql database

I want to convert to PDO as I have been informed that PHP will be removing the old mysql_ functions soon and I assume this means the pg_ functions will disappear as well.

I only ever use:

pg_connect/mysql_connect & mysql_select_db
pg_query/mysql_query
pg_result/mysql_result
pg_numrows/mysql_numrows (for checking if there is  a result, or looping through resultset)
pg_fetch_array

I have thousands of queries and don't relish the idea of going through every one.

Is it possible just to go through and make global changes in my code to implement PDO?

Comment: The `pg_*` function don't go anywhere. It's only the `mysql_*` which will be deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: That makes things a tad easier - thanks

Comment: Does that mean I can just do a global change mysql=mysqli in the interim?

Comment: yes, but you will need to add `global $conn;` line in all the functions manually, as mysqli always takes 2 parameters, not one.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean I can just do a global change mysql=mysqli in the interim?

Well the answer is somewhat complex and can be divided into 2 parts.
Let's look into the question first:
There are actually 2 possible reasons to change your codes.

1. Deprecation process for mysql extension.
2. Making your code safer against SQL injection.

For the first one, it is not actually an urgent reason.
It will be deprecated in the not-released-yet version and removed in not-even-known version. So, to hit whatever trouble you will need to have a PHP version with removed mysql support. According to my experience, new versions moves on the shared hosts slowly, and you have 7 to 10 years ahead.

For the second reason, simple bulk search and replace will do no good at all.
So, instead of going for this option in a hurry, I'd go for gradual refactoring, eventually replacing old code with better versions.